# How to delete files available in s3 bucket

Tags: python

I have written a code to delete older files and and keep the latest one. My code is working in local but wanted to apply the same code when accessing AWS s3 bucket folder to perform the similar operation.

The code working fine when providing local path.

```
import os
import glob

path = r'C:\Desktop\MyFolder'
allfiles =[os.path.basename(file) for file in  glob.glob(path + '\*.*')]
diff_pattern=set()
deletefile=[]

for file in allfiles:
    diff_pattern.add('_'.join(file.split('_',2)[:2]))

print('Pattern Found - ',diff_pattern)
for pattern in diff_pattern:
    patternfiles=[os.path.basename(file) for file in  glob.glob(path + '\\'+pattern+'_*.*')]
    patternfiles.sort()
    if len(patternfiles)>1:
        deletefile=deletefile+patternfiles[:len(patternfiles)-1]

print('Files Need to Delete - ',deletefile)

for file in deletefile:
    os.remove(path+'\\'+file)
print('File Deleted')
```

I expect the same code to work for AWS s3 buckets. Below is the files format and example with there status(keep/delete) that I'm working with.

file format: file_name_yyyyMMdd.txt

v_xyz_20190501.txt   Delete
v_xyz_20190502.txt   keep
v_xyz_20190430.txt   Delete
v_abc_20190505.txt   Keep
v_abc_20190504.txt   Delete

Comment: `os.remove` won't work. You'll need to execute `aws s3 rm` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access S3 files like local path.

You may need to use boto3 library in python to access s3 folders.

Here is a sample for you to see how it works..

https://dluo.me/s3databoto3